# pandas map function to data frame across all columns and one fixed column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with 5 columns, `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'`

I would like to apply a function to the first 4 columns (`'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'`) that takes two inputs `X[i]` and `E[i]` for row `i` where `X` is one of the first four columns.

Ignoring `E[i]`, this is fairly straightforward:

```
def do_something(value):
    return some_transformation(value)

df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].applymap(do_something)
```

Similarly, if I have a constant value I can do it with `map`:

```
def do_something(value, i):
    return some_transformation(value, i)

df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].map(lambda f: do_something(f, 6))
```

But how do I do this if instead of `6` I want to pass in the value of `E` in the same row?

Comment: Try vectorizing your function with `np.vectorize` and passing that to apply?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not sure if that is possible in my case because the value of `E[i]` is an object I need to call methods on

Comment: It should be possible, since `vectorize` lets your function take two arrays but works on one set of elements at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.vectorize`, you can pass columns to the function while actual computation happens over each set of elements.

```
def do_something(x, y):
    return some_transformation(x, y)

v = np.vectorize(do_something)
df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].apply(v, args=(df['E'], ))
```

Comment: Awesome. this does exactly what I need, and is clean.